# How can I put different colors for the different elements of a single dimension

Tags: tableau-api

How can I set different colors for the different elements of a single dimension with Tableau Desktop?

[image]

I want the colors in fields of dimension and not like the picture.

Thank you

Comment: Its not completely clear what you're asking. Do you want the text to be colored? Can you describe your goal more precisely?

Answer (score 0):

You can drag that same dimension on the Color mark in the Marks area, which by default is displayed below filters, right to the Data area.

To change the colors that Tableau assigns by default you can click on the Color mark and use "Select Colors": it will open a window where you can select the color you want for each value of the dimension you're using.

**Edit**

Unfortunately you cannot color the background of a dimension axis. You can achieve the same result with a trick though:

1. Drag the dimension to rows
2. Double-click in columns and write `MIN(1)`
3. From the marks dropdown, make sure `Bar` is selected
4. Drag the dimension to the `Color` mark
5. Drag the dimension to the `Label` mark
6. From the `Label` mark, set the horizontal alignment to either left or center
7. From the `Label` mark, mark the flag to allow labels to overlap other marks
8. From the `Size` mark, crank the size all the way up
9. Right-click on the dimension from the rows area and unselect *Show Header*
10. Right click on the `MIN(1)` axis below the graph, click *Edit Axis*, select *Fixed* among the *Range* options and fix start and end to 0 and 1 respectively
11. Right click on the `MIN(1)` from the columns area and unselect *Show Header*

Of course adjustments can be made to better suit your needs, but this should give you an idea of the whole process.

Comment: thank you but it's not what i want. I spoke about fields of a single dimension

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Could you please provide an example of the desired outcome?

Comment: @senartval edited my answer, let me know if it's what you need :)